# Three.js—rotation around arbitrary line

Tags: rotation, three.js

I am starting with Three.js so I might have misunderstood some basics of the concept. I have a usual 3d scene with a hierarchy like this:

```
.
+-container @(0,0,0) (Object3d, no own geometry)
 +-child 1 @(1,1,1)
 +-child 2 @(1, -2, 5)
 +-child 3 @(-4, -2, -3)
 .
 .
 . more should come
```

all »children« of the »container« are imported models from Blender. What I would like to do is to rotate the whole container around a pivot axis based on the current selection, which should be one of the children.

Image three cubes in Blender, all selected with the 3d cursor at center of first in location and center of transformation. A rotation transforms all cubes, but the rotation is relative to the first in selection.

In terms of three.js, what would like to do is to rotate the container, so that the rotation is applied to all children.

To do that I think that the following steps should do the trick:

1. create a matrix,
2. translate that matrix by the negative of the selected objects position
3. rotate that matrix
4. translate the matrix back to the selected objects position
5. apply the transform to the container

I have tried the following code but the result is just wrong:

```
var sp = selection.position.clone(),
    m = new THREE.Matrix4();

selection.localToWorld(sp);
m.setPosition(sp.clone().negate());

//I've used makeRotationX for testing purposes, should be replaced with quaternion rotation later on…
m = m.multiply(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(2*180/Math.PI));
m = m.multiply(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(sp.x,sp.y,sp.z));

this._container.applyMatrix(m);
```

Thanks for help!

**UPDATE**

**sign error**—this works:

```
var sp = selection.position.clone(),
    m = new THREE.Matrix4();

m.makeTranslation(sp.x,sp.y,sp.z);
m.multiply(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(0.1));
m.multiply(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(-sp.x,-sp.y,-sp.z));

this._container.applyMatrix(m);
```

**BUT** that code does not really look that good, creating three matrices for that single operating seems to bit of overhead, what is the usual »three.js-way«?

**UPDATE #2**

Due to the comment here is an image describing what I would like to do:

[image]

The »arrows« at the origin stand for the parent container and the cube, the sphere and the cone are its »children«. The red line shows the line I would like rotate the parent around, this way the rotation is applied to all children.

`rotateOnAxis()` takes a Vector as axis, so the line the objects rotates around crosses its origin.

Comment: If `object.rotateOnAxis( axis, angle )` or `object.rotateX( angle )` are not what you want, then you will have to provide a simple, live example to demonstrate what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is your question "How do I rotate an object around an axis that is offset from the object?"?

Comment: Well, probably yes. As I see, my last update is not shown. Therein I just wrote that it was a sign error, it is working now. But nevertheless, thanks for your help, I am gonna reedit the question.

Comment: Thanks!  You initial edit (sign error) works great.  I was able to rotate a group of objects around my camera without adding the group as a child.